# Adding a function to ajax dynamically created elements in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, dynamic

Basically I am in the process of creating a movie info app using ajax, I have ran into a problem that I can't seem to solve. Once I have created and ajax request I am then dynamically creating content and adding it to the page.
This is my dynamically created content.

```
   output +=
  `<div class="box">
    <div class="box-image">
     <img src="${val.Poster}" alt="${val.Title}">
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <h4 class="box-title">${val.Title}</h4>
        <p class="year">${val.Year}</p>
        <a href="#" class="modal-trigger" id="modalTrigger">Modal Trigger</a>
    </div>
  </div>`.
```

It is the anchor tag that is giving me problems, I want to add a function to it, so that I can open up a modal. I would also like a way of preventing its default behaviour inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener for clicks to the body document and select for the element you're creating as show below:

```
$("body").on('click', "a.modal-trigger", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

```js
$("#ajax").click(function() {
  $("#output").append(
    $("<a/>")
    .attr("id", "modalTrigger")
    .attr("class", "modal-trigger")
    .attr("href", "#")
    .text("modal")
  );
});

$("body").on('click', "a.modal-trigger", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('modal!');
  $("#output").append("modal!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="ajax">
Make Ajax Request
</button>

  <div id="output">

  </div>
</body>
```

console.log('modal!');
    });

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer solved your issue or any other does in the future, please mark it as accepted.